# Found: core.apexpages.el.adapters.ApexListELAdapter

Tags: apex, visualforce

Trying to display the all account records in a drop down list like shown in  following.

[image]

By clicking the button after selecting an account, I am getting the following issue.

> Return type of an Apex action method must be a PageReference. Found:
>   core.apexpages.el.adapters.ApexListELAdapter

I never get any issue before to when i re-modified. I perfectly got the account and its ID, But when I modified the code is asking about `PageReference`.

I can solve this issue using `PageReference`, But I need a solution with out using `PageReference`.

This is what i tried so far,

Apex class:

```
public class AccountDropdown {

    Public String Accid {set;get;}
    List<Selectoption> options = new List<Selectoption>();

    Public List<Selectoption> getrecords() {

        options.add(new Selectoption('Nothing', 'Select a Account'));
        for(Account a : [select id,name from account]) {
            options.add(new Selectoption(a.id, a.name));
        }
        return options;
    }
}
```

Visualforce page:

```
<apex:page controller="AccountDropdown" showHeader="false" >
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock id="one">
            <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!accid}">
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!records}" />
            </apex:selectList>      
            <apex:commandButton value="Submit" action="{!getrecords}" reRender="one"/>
                <apex:param value="{!accid}" assignTo="{!accid}"/>
        </apex:pageBlock>
        {!accid}
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Your action on button is doing nothing. Either replace with a method which returns void or pageReference or remove the action attribute

2. instead of rerendering the ONE pageblock, render a output panel which wraps the  **{!accid}**
3. your param isn't doing nothing as it's placed outside commandbutton tag

**code:**

```
<apex:page controller="AccountDropdown" showHeader="false" >
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock id="one">
        <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!accid}">
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!records}" />
        </apex:selectList>      
        <apex:commandButton value="Submit"  reRender="testPanel"/>
            <apex:param value="{!accid}" assignTo="{!accid}"/>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:outputPanel id="testPanel">
    {!accid}
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:form>
```

Comment: Can you please explain me, If action is nothing doing, why i am facing issue?

Comment: please take a look at above code. paste it and it should work.
the problem is your action is looking for a method with name getrecords which returns null or page reference. In your code, there is one more method with name getrecords which returns a selectOption

Comment: Its working fine when using `output panel` tag. But, why it actually coming when i use `getrecords` method in action. The reason i am asking about.

Comment: i told you the reason why it won't work. from whatever code you posted, it should never work. should i ask you for any proof that it's working?

Answer (score 0):

You have the `apex:command` button action method set as:

```
action="{!getrecords}"
```

which as a method that returns a list (and the same code used to provide the select options) rather than a method that returns a `PageReference` (or `void`). Add a separate method of the right signature and reference that method name in the `action` or remove the `action` altogether.

Comment: Can you please provide piece of code?

Comment: @KSKumaar Remove the `action` altogether and nest the `apex:param` inside the `apex:commandButton` as Erkan suggests.

Comment: Yeah. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Param must be inside command button tags like below:

```
<apex:page controller="AccountDropdown" showHeader="false" >
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock id="one">
            <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!accid}">
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!records}" />
            </apex:selectList>      
            <apex:commandButton value="Submit" action="{!getrecords}" reRender="one">
                <apex:param value="{!accid}" assignTo="{!accid}"/>
</apex:commandButton>
        </apex:pageBlock>
        {!accid}
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: May be, the answer given by you is not a problem in visualforce page.